# Length of array upon selections

Tags: arrays, applescript

how to declare the length of array as a variable（・・？
I need to declare an array at first to input the selections in the following codes but the numbers of input data is yet to determine at first place.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set TargetF to (path to desktop folder as text) & ""
    set filePath to ""
    set arrayfile to {"", "", "", "", "", ""}


    select (every item where name extension is "mp4") of (TargetF as alias)
    set sel to selection

    if sel is not {} then
        repeat with i from 1 to (count of sel)
            set filePath to item i of sel as text
            set item i of arrayfile to filePath
        end repeat
    end if


    tell application "VLC" to open arrayfile


end tell
```

one more Question:
AppleScript column error
setting the visibility of OS X window column fails using these codes

```
set width of column id name column of list view options of front window to 10
set visible of column id version column of list view options of front window to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no arrays in AppleScript, you can use lists. That is very simple, you can either use `set beginning of L to yourvalue` or `set end of L to yourvalue` and have the list element be automatically created, so the size of your list increases dynamically (you need to create an empty list first with something like `set L to {}`. Here you can use the length property to read off the length of the list: `set ll to length of L`, or you can count the items: `set ll to (count L)`.

If you insist on using a static array, here is something I use:

```
on newZeroList(nrOfElms)
    script lst
        property rowOf10 : {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    end script
    -- make the first row
    if nrOfElms < 10 then
        copy items 1 thru nrOfElms of lst's rowOf10 to aRow

    else if nrOfElms = 10 then
        copy lst's rowOf10 to aRow
    else
        set fullRows to nrOfElms div 10
        set restRows to nrOfElms mod 10
        copy lst's rowOf10 to aRow
        repeat with i from 2 to fullRows
            copy lst's rowOf10 to holder
            set aRow to aRow & holder
        end repeat
        if restRows = 1 then
            set end of aRow to 0
        else if restRows > 1 then
            copy items 1 thru restRows of lst's rowOf10 to holder
            set aRow to aRow & holder
        end if
    end if
    return aRow
end newZeroList
```